# Use variables from settings.xml but override with environment variables in Maven

Tags: maven

I'm trying to use a property in my Maven POM file to specify the URL / username / password to a private repository. I would like to get the value for this property from a settings.xml file (from either the global, user or project settings file) but use the value from a specific environment variable to override any of that if it is set.

I've searched a bunch and I've found some references to using build profiles which doesn't seem to be quite what I need, but then again I'm not very fluent in Maven so I might just be missing something there. I feel like an idiot because I would think this is a pretty common use case.

In general I'm not too keen on defining secrets (passwords or API keys) in environment variables but for now we need to do that to avoid having to change the whole CI pipeline.

Comment: If you have a property in the `settings.xml` you can override it on command line. This is not good enough for you?

Comment: @JFabianMeier unfortunately not really, no. The problem with that is then I will have to change the CI which I'm trying to avoid (would have to modify the way Maven is started to shuffle the necessary environment variables around).

Comment: Credentials etc. should be done in credentials store of jenkins...Jenkins config file provider plugin handles that case perfectly...Also for other credentials that can also being defined jenkins  (See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)...

Comment: @StFS Then I do not think this is possible.

Comment: @khmarbaise we're not using Jenkins... but yes... the CI probably needs to be fixed eventually, just not now.

Comment: It does not matter which CI solution you are using...every CI solution has features like that...

Comment: I know that. But as I said, the question isn't about fixing the CI solution, that will be done later.

Comment: AFAIK, a property set in the `settings.xml` can only be changed by setting it on command line. You might of course write your own Maven plugin that checks against environment variables and resets properties.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. In the end, I got this working using Maven build profiles. They seem to be simply overwriting the values of what's defined in the pom.xml file (globally) at runtime. To me, this stinks to high heaven but it works for now.